# Can't start Express.js application with npm start, it starts with Docker, but now Docker doesn't work either

Tags: node.js, docker, express, npm, hyper-v

I am developing a Node Express API with a React front end with Docker, I develop on  Win 10, but the prod runs on an Ubuntu VPS.

Everything worked fine until yesterday Docker stopped working with error:

> 'Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name "DockerNAT"'.

After trying all suggestions on related issues on github, stackoverflow, microsoft, etc., nothing worked, so I decided to just go on without using Docker, so I tried running my API with `npm start`, which worked before, but now it does not. It seems like it's stuck; nothing happens, no error messages, nothing, yet after even hours it simply just doesn't start.

My React front end still runs with `npm start`. I haven't changed anything in related files since it was running with Docker previously, and now I have NO IDEA what could be the problem.

Here is my start in API package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
```

`www` is in the right folder, it worked with Docker.

Here is the Docker file of the API:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8.11.4
WORKDIR /api
COPY package*.json /api/
RUN npm install
COPY . /api/
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml for running both projects together, which worked flawlessly:

```
version: "2.1"
networks:
webappnetwork:
    driver: bridge
services:
    website:
         build: ./website
         restart: always
         ports:
              - "3000:3000"
         volumes:
              - ./website:/website
              - /website/node_modules
         networks:
              - webappnetwork
    api:
         build: ./api
         restart: always
         ports:
              - "9000:9000"
         volumes:
              - ./api:/api
              - /api/node_modules
         networks:
              - webappnetwork
```

There was no Windows update before Docker stopped working, Docker was also already the most recent version and I haven't changed a single line of code.

I checked my Docker log files, at first it said:

> couldn't get DockerNAT switch

but I reinstalled different versions multiple times and now it says:

> MobyLinux does not exist

At first it existed; I checked it in Hyper-V, but now it's not there. Hyper-V network adapters also disappeared, they cannot be seen in Device Manager.

I would really appreciate if someone could think of something to try, whether in connection with the Docker/Hyper-V error or why `npm start` could be stuck.

Comment: did you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273005/cannot-start-docker-on-windows-10-pro 
or just use linux :D

Comment: What do you get after running `npm start`?

Comment: @AmrRagaey nothing, just stays at > node ./bin/www with cursor blinking

Comment: That's mean it's running. Check `http://localhost:9000`

Comment: @AmrRagaey omg so sorry that's right, it's running, i'm so dumb i was so used to docker writing out a lot of stuff i was exprecting it and i have been so exhausted finding a solution for the DockerNAT problem i didnt even check localhost after npm start - thanks!

Comment: @DoraJurievnaDusyn Nahhh, you're not dumb; that happens to the best of us. :p We tend to always immediately think the worst is happening and start looking for complicated reasons for it. lol

Comment: Is somebody making an answer here?